# Symfony2 Form Field data_class Validation doesnt works

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, field

I've this type with the following validation:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name', null, array(
        'description' => 'The category name'));

    $builder->add('model', 'form_type', array(
        'data_class'  => 'Foo\BarBundle\Model\Foo'
    ));
}
```

The bar type:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name', null);
}
```

Validation of the first type:

```
Foo\BarBundle\Model\Bar:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotNull:
                message : system.error.alert.null
```

Validation of the second type:

```
Foo\BarBundle\Model\Foo:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotNull:
                message : system.error.alert.null
```

Everything works as expected, but symfony doesnt validates the second form type. Anyone know what to do? Please tell me if you need more info.

Thanks.

Comment: can you post also your code in the controller where you instantiate the form that doesn't work?

Comment: Of course. Please take a look to http://pastebin.com/qsDJ6qZc. I've pastedbin the code there. If you need more, please tell me. Thank you.

Comment: try `$form = $this->createForm($type, $model);` in your controller

Comment: This seems to work. However, symfony doesn't bind the error message to the form. I've created a second pastebin. http://pastebin.com/ywVPi3Qg

Comment: have a look at this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/gc1jQyH2)

Comment: Hey..thanks again. But it doesnt work. I noticed, that also the validation of the parent type doesnt work. Dont know what happens there.

Comment: If I use submit() the parent form type will be validated and symfony binds the error message to the form fields. If I use handleRequest(), the parent form type will be validated, but symfony doesnt bind the error messages to the form fields.

Comment: I am not exactly sure, but isn't [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#cascade-validation) what you're looking for?

Comment: Oh...my...god...lol. Didnt know that there were such an option. Its working like a charm now. Thank you very much. ponciste thank you too.